# How to access the refs after the universal React app finished server side first screen rendering?

Tags: reactjs, universal, refs

I have a universal React + Redux app which render the first screen page on server side, then the browser side ReactJS will finish the rest of tasks.

Currently I met an issue, I can't access the refs using 
1. `this.refs[xxx]`
2. `ref={(ref) => this.xxx = ref}`

```
componentDidMount() {
    // The code in handleScroll cannot get this.xxx, as it would print the error 
    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of null
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    // Code below can get the rect numbers.
    console.log(this.xxx.getBoundingClientRect());
}

handleScroll(event) {
   if (this.xxx !== null) {
     console.log(this.xxx.getBoundingClientRect());
   }
 }
```

I need get the ReactDom element while user is scrolling the page and do some thing on that element. But if I can only access refs in componentDidMount(), how can I make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: does your react component getting mounted after rendering in browser ?

Comment: @abhirathore2006 yes, the component has been rendered in browser, and all the refs are accessible in componentDidMount method after that.

Comment: so your issue is resolved right?

Comment: @abhirathore2006 yes, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging, put a breakpoint in handleScroll to check what all you get in 'this'. Can you see any other refs, or state?

You can try binding 'this' to handleScroll, if that helps, like:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
```

Comment: I figured out the problem and solution on the way home and you are correct. Thanks.